# disable full-text search for webtop simple search component

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, webtop

In the simple search component in webtop, how do you disable full text search and just use the database?

I would like to keep the advanced search searching full text.

I understand that fulltext search can be disabled comepletely in the dfc.properties or filtered by type and role using a dql hints file but I cannot find anything about how to disable it only in simple search!

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the search component and in your extended component override *buildQuery()* method. This way you could write your own query. Glancing the developer forum, it should be enough to execute query without SEARCH TOPIC function.

Answer (score 1):

A solution similar to Miki's that seems to be working.

Extend the search component but modify the `onClickSearch ()` javascript in your custom **titlebar.jsp** call and ovverride the *postComponentJumpEvent* by passing it the modified dql query.

```
function onClickSearch ()
{
var contentPage = eval(getAbsoluteFramePath("content"));
if (contentPage != null)
{
var text = document.getElementById("txtSearch");
callBlur(text);
var strValue = text.value;
if (strValue != "" && strValue != "<%=strSearch %>")
{

var query = "select * from dm_folder where upper(object_name) like upper('%" + strValue + "%')"; //or any query

postComponentJumpEvent(null, "search", "content", "queryType","dql","query", query);
```